# Подборка dataset для построения моделей машинного обучения

Tags: машинное-обучение, dataset

В этом вопросе собираются списки датасетов и утилит для разметки данных. Просьба редактировать существующий ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Русско-китайские параллельные тексты. ~8млн строк](https://www.kaggle.com/averkij/russian-chinese-parallel-corpora)
- [Древняя коллекция репозиториев с данными. Очень много старых и неактуальных данных](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php)
- [Коллекция датасаетов сообщества ODS](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZSLP1McnXv0FtOd9t7dMp3AfaiusvaGwWV0F9g2pbho/edit#gid=0)
- [Данные с фотографиями лиц людей по национальностям](https://my-cccp.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/opredelenie-nacionalnosti.jpg)
- [Инструменты для разметки данных](https://github.com/heartexlabs/awesome-data-labeling)
- [kaggle datasets](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets)
- [Коллекция датасетов по саммаризации текстов](https://github.com/mathsyouth/awesome-text-summarization)
- [Компания Apple показывает статистику мобильности своих пользователей в связи с COVID-19](https://www.apple.com/covid19/mobility)
- [CSSEGISandData COVID-19](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19)
- [Утилита для ручной разметки данных](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hZpvoN-pEmpzYzEUYSJufUYSXXfXgEaY)
- [Фотографии крыш домов](https://www.crowdai.org/challenges/mapping-challenge) [1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EGw9EJLGik3ekAagBr6-SyMq8mcPJlQR/view?usp=drive_open)
- [Similarwed dataset. Категоризатор доменов](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19fN9R4lrIu2ANT6OajTbDTRIaO4j6Qku/view)
- [1941-1945](https://foto.pamyat-naroda.ru/) Данные с сайта министерства обороны о ветеранах. Содержат примерно миллион записей.
- [The corpus is a 12.9 billion tokens sample of the lib.rus.ec book collection (150GB of raw text)](https://russe.nlpub.org/downloads/)
- [Коллекция книг на русском языке](https://tatianashavrina.github.io/taiga_site/)
- [toxic dataset на русском языке](http://tpc.at.ispras.ru/prakticheskoe-zadanie-2015/)
- [Russian Language Toxic Comments](https://www.kaggle.com/blackmoon/russian-language-toxic-comments)
- [Коллекция фотографий людей в масках (китайцы)](https://github.com/X-zhangyang/Real-World-Masked-Face-Dataset)
- [Коллекция данных по COVID-19 в России](https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/8b8ygpt596/2)
- [Коллекция данных по COVID-19 в России, созданная при поддержке INVITRO](https://covid19faq.ru/l/ru/article/smgcguuguh-hand-collected-coronavirus-data-sources)
- [Изображения и описания к ним](https://www.kaggle.com/tapakah68/impressive-dataset)
- [Корпусы текстов на португальском языке](https://lionbridge.ai/datasets/best-portuguese-language-datasets-for-machine-learning/)